# Scikit learn: forget previous train data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In scikit learn I have a model (in my case a Linear model)

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

I can train this model with some data

```
clf.fit(x1,y1)
```

But if I call again `fit` it will continue training the model.

```
clf.fit(x2,y2)
```

Now clf is a model trained with both (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

If I want to start training from 0, I can create again the model by redefining `clf`

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x1,y1)
# save the model
# ...
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(x2,y2)
```

However I don't want to define clf again:

Basically the type of regressor is chosen before, something like:

```
if params.linear_algorithm == 'least_squares':
    clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
elif params.linear_algorithm == 'ridge':
    clf = linear_model.Ridge()
elif params.linear_algorithm == 'lasso':
    clf = linear_model.Lasso()
```

So I don't want inside my train function to redefine `clf` with all the conditional block, instead I just want to take `clf`, clean it from previous trainings and reuse it to train another set of data.

Does clf have a method to clean what has learned so far, so when I call clf.fit(x2,y2) is only trained on this data?

**EDIT:** You guys are right, the training is overwriten everytime.

My problem is that I'm saving the model in a dictionary, and it just take the reference to clf, so each time clf is retrained all previous saves are changed.

Redefining clf everytime creates a new object so each save points now so a different model

Example

```
for i in range(3):
   # get the x and y
   # ...
   clf.fit(x,y)
   model[i] = clf
```

Any idea how to save every time a different model instead of pointing all model[i] to the same clf?

Comment: Is it related to this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916255/sklearn-how-to-reset-a-regressor-or-classifier-object-in-sknn

Comment: unless `warm_start` is `True` the call to fit resets the classifier according to the docs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. According to the [Scikit-Learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html):

> Calling fit() more than once will overwrite what was learned by any previous fit().

You can therefore use your code safely and it will achieve what you need.

Comment: It actually doesn't, I have a loop where each iteration trains different data. If inside the loop I redeclare clf it works, if I declare clf before the loop and only firt inside the loop then it doesn't work

Comment: That is very weird, since it's specifically mentioned in the documentation. Can you post your entire code?

Comment: Yup, problem was when saving the model to a dict, what is being saved is a ref to clf

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki regarding your latest edit, what happens if you do model[i] = clf.fit(x2, x3)?

Comment: the right question is how to save a model and how to load it when need to classify new data, for exemple "with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    cPickle.dump(cl, fid)"

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it overwrites any existing information from before.  Scikit Learn docs specify that.  Unless you use `warm_start = True`, `fit()` calls will overwrite existing data.